# Siren of shame build monitor, unable to connect to TFS 2008 or TFS 2012

Tags: tfs, tfsbuild

I'm trying to set up the [siren of shame build monitor](http://sirenofshame.com/buildmonitor), but for some reason can't connect to my TFS.

TFS itself is running on port 8080, and TFSBuild on 9192 - but putting `http://build-server:8080` or trying other ports does not work...

[image]
[image: error message]

(Update 1) I've downloaded the source, and also looked using Wireshark into what is happening when it tries to authenticate. I'm confused, as the code is using standard .net Libraries for TFS - Microsoft.TeamFoundation.dll (v2.0.50727). It seems to be looking for web services that do not exist if I look in IIS on the server - namely `POST /TeamFoundation/Administration/v3.0/LocationService.asmx`

Is it the case that this is not compatible with TFS 2008 at all, and only TFS 2010 will work?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I downloaded the "Siren of Shame" to have a look.

To connect you need to enter the URL for TFS in the following format

`http://tfs-Application-Server:8080/tfs`

[image: Siren config screen]

Note that it attaches to the TFS server not the build server (or build controller).

However having connected to TFS it looks like a pain to configure. It correctly detected all of the Team Project Collections that I have in TFS but when I selected one of the collections it wasn't showing any running builds. So I tried selecting a single Team Project, once again no builds were displayed. Finally I selected a build that I knew was running, only then did it show up in Siren of Shame.

I have thousands of builds and I don't want to have to select each one individually to be able to monitor it. At the very least I want to be able to select a team project and monitor all of the builds in that project with one click

There are a number of alternatives out there. But none of them are great
http://teambuildscreen.codeplex.com/

http://buildmonitor.codeplex.com/

http://tfsbuildinspector.codeplex.com/

Comment: That still does not work for me. If I put that URL into a browser I get Page Not Found. There is no 'tfs' virtual directory when I look in IIS manager on the TFS server...my virtual directories are: Build, Services, Version Control, Warehouse, WorkItemTracking.

I've tried those other tools already, the main reason I wanted to go for Siren of Shame is because I can play sound alerts on build failure and success...if I can get it to work that is!

Comment: Sorry, I just noticed that you're using TFS 2008. I don't have a 2008 server to try it on but you should be able to use `http://tfs:8080/`. This should be your application tier server, not your build server

Comment: We have both source control and build running from the same server. I hope this is not causing the problem, but they are running on different ports (as given in the original question).

Comment: It shouldn't cause a problem although I wouldn't recommend it. Looks like a bug in the application. I'd contact the owner of the app and ask for some documentation (there doesn't appear to be any)

Comment: Their support email address sends a bounce back :( I've added an update to my question - not sure what my next plan of attack will be...

Comment: I've finally got this working.

We've set up a TFS 2012 server, and use the URL you suggest (http://tfs-Application-Server:8080/tfs)